# How to use moment in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the moment module in my component,like

```
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';

console.log(this.today = moment().startOf('day').fromNow());
```

How can i use the pipes available in this moment module ,can any one provide me some pipes available in moment module.

Comment: Check [this out](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment)

Comment: from the link provided by you,i see import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment'; there but i am using import * as moment from 'moment/moment';

Comment: i am using moment module

Comment: Your question is that you wanted some pipes right? Moment is just a vanilla JS librabry. It has no knowledge of pipes. The library I linked to creates a bunch of pipes you can use for Moment. in an Angular 2 application. Otherwise you will need to implement everything yourslf

Comment: when i use this one @Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    Last updated: {{myDate | amTimeAgo}}
  `
})

Comment: it says cannot find pipe 'amTimeAgo'

Comment: You need to `@NgModule.imports: [ MomentModule ]` into whatever module your component is declared in

Comment: Thank you very much,its wrkng fine

Comment: what is the syntax to use the same for textbox binding?